# How do I upload multiple images and associate with a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

## Errors when attempting to upload multiple images

#### Description of issue:

I have a model, Vehicle which has vehicle information as well as a cover photo. To add images for a gallery, I have a second model VehicleImage with a foreign key to Vehicle. I'm attempting to upload multiple images with a single file picker and save those all to a defined path (/media/vehicles/vehicle#/) I've tried different views to no avail. Right now i'm getting the following error.

```
Raised by:  main.views.ImageFieldView
No vehicle image found matching the query
```

Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm still learning but I work at it every day.

models.py

```
def vehicle_directory_path(instance, filename):
    #! file will be uploaded to media_cdn/vehicle/<id>/<filename>.<ext>
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    name = filename.split('.')[0]
    vehicle = Vehicle.objects.get(id=instance.id)
    return 'vehicles/{0}/{1}.{2}'.format(vehicle.id, name, ext)

class VehicleImage(models.Model):

    vehicle = models.ForeignKey('Vehicle', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=vehicle_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class ImageFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image_field = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
    class Meta:
        model = VehicleImage
        exclude = ('image', 'vehicle')
```

views.py

```
class ImageFieldView(CreateView):
    model = VehicleImage
    form_class = ImageFieldForm
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'form': ImageFieldForm}
        return render(request, 'main/vehicle_upload.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('image_field')
        if form.is_valid():
            for file in files:
                instance = VehicleImage(
                    vehicle=Vehicle.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']),
                    image=file)
                instance.save()
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    path('vehicles/', views.vehicles, name='vehicles'),
    path('vehicles/detail/<int:pk>/', views.VehicleDetail.as_view(), name='vehicle_detail'),
    path('vehicles/edit/<int:pk>/', views.VehicleEdit.as_view(), name='vehicle_edit'),
    path('vehicles/images/upload/<int:pk>', views.ImageFieldView.as_view(),name='vehicle_image_upload'),
#    path('vehicle/image/add/<int:pk>/', views.VehicleEdit.as_view(), name='vehicle_image'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Suggested Edit: Still getting the same error

```
        vehicles = Vehicle.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                VehicleImage.objects.create(vehicle=vehicles, image=f)
            return self.form_valid(form)
```

Comment: First thing. Don't do this: ```instance = VehicleImage(
                    vehicle=Vehicle.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']),
                    image=file)```. You need to find your ```Vehicle``` object first and only if it exists pass it to ```VehicleImale```.

Comment: If in your ```post``` you want to create ```VehicleImage``` instance for each of files, then change code to ```instance = VehicleImage.objects.create(**params)```. And you don't need ```instance.save()``` line anymore.

Comment: Or even ```VehicleImage.objects.create(**params)```, without ```instance =``` - this redundant for now.

Comment: @YevheniiM.
I've changed the above portions that you mentioned and it now looks like this
`
        vehicles = Vehicle.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']),
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                VehicleImage.objects.create(vehicle=vehicles, image=f)
            return self.form_valid(form)
`

I'm still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: show your ```urls.py``` with ```ImageFieldView``` usage. Seems like you forgot to add ```pk``` to your url.

Comment: It must be like this (Django 2): ```path('your-url/<int:pk>/', ImageFieldView.as_view())```.

Comment: @YevheniiM. I updated the post with the current urls.py config and it looks like that portion should be good unless I'm missing something there.

Comment: Problem is that your View trying to find ```VehicleImage``` by pk, but you want get it by ```Vehicle```'s pk. So change model in your ```ImageFieldView``` to ```Vehicle``` or get vehicle pk in ```request.data``` instead of ```kwargs```.

Comment: @YevheniiM. I feel like I need to leave the model set to VehicleImage because that's the model that I'm trying to write the data to. I'm not seeing any method of getting the pk from request.data. Do I need to set the whole thing up differently? No pressure, I appreciate you helping, but would you be able to show an example? I feel like this should be pretty simple but I'm feeling stumped.

Comment: You need to pass in your POST data info about ```Vehicle```. So you can update your ```ImageFieldForm``` to have ```vehicle``` field too. But make this field hidden because is you but not user chooses vehicle.

Comment: And now you can remove ```<int:pk>``` from your ```vehicles/images/upload/``` url.

Comment: @YevheniiM. Thank you again, I'm confused, is that not what's happening with `vehicles = Vehicle.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])`?

If I remove the `<int:pk>` then how will the page know which vehicle to associate the images with?

The scenario is such that, I'm on a Vehicle Details page and have an option to click to add additional photos. The link takes the vehicle.id and passes it to the upload page to know where it came from.

Comment: Ok, imagine that images are just a tab on a Vehicle page. You'll be updating ```VehicleImage``` objects, but without ```Vehicle``` you don't need them at all. That's why it's ok to change model to ```Vehicle``` instead of ```VehicleImage```. You may somehow rewrite your code to make it clearer, but that's idea behind this.

Comment: See also [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) for this purpose.

Comment: @YevheniiM. with formsets you seem to need to know the amount of extras to use and what I need is to loop through the list without limiting the amount of images unless I'm mistaken. I've looked at many ways to accomplish this and there aren't a lot of answers unfortunately that I've found.

Comment: For now I must go. But tomorrow I'll try to help you if you do not find the answer.

Comment: @YevheniiM.
Thank you again, I'll be working on it all night ha ha. I feel like it should be an easy fix. I've tried to follow the Django documentation on Uploading multiple files so in theory it should be taking the files, saving them to the filepath but it's proving more difficult.

Comment: Have you found any solution?